# What authentic information is available on 'Shri Kripalu Maharaj (श्री कृपालु महाराज)'?

Tags: krishna, guru, sects, kashi, jagadguru

Kripalu Maharaj, formally known as Jagadguru ShrīKripālu Jī Mahārāj was a Bhakti Yoga spiritual leader with sole focus on Kṛṣṇa Bhakti.

On the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripalu_Maharaj), following sweeping claims have been made about him:

> He was awarded the title of Jagadguru (world teacher) at the age of 34 by Kashi Vidvat Parishat (the oldest and most recognised body of Varanasi's intellectuals) on Makar Sankranti, 14 January 1957.

So, **basically they are claiming him to be on a par level with likes of Ādi Śaṅkarācārya, Rāmānujācārya, Nimbārkāchārya & Madhvāchārya.**

However, furthermore, another ostentatious claim is made:

> He was also awarded, by the Kashi Vidvat Parishat, the title Samanvaya-Acharya, i.e., He analyses and reconciles the meaning of all the scriptures, the six philosophies and the (seemingly contradictory) teachings of other previous Jagadgurus. **After being awarded Jagadguruttam (the foremost among Jagadgurus)**....

**Thus, they claim that the Kashi Vidvat Parishat conferred on him to be the best of all the jagadgurus or any great ācāryas known.**

The citation references used in the Wikipedia seems OK in terms of authenticity, atleast on surface level, they look fine.

Even his organization's page, obviously says the same about him. Here: [Jagadguru Kripalu Parishat](https://www.jkp.org.in/life-story-jagadguruttam/).

However, no information seem to be available on his lineage or his guru or acharya.

---

### Questions:

- 1. Who was his guru or preceptor, and to which lineage/saṃpradāya Kripaluji belong?
- 2. How authentic is this narrative of him being a Jagadguru? Is this found in the annals of Kashi Vidvat Parishat? Did any official from the Parishat comment on this, in support or refutal?
- 3. Is the Kashi Vidvat Parishat, a recognized /authorized body to declare or confer just about anyone with these decorative epithets?
- 4. Is the term - 'Jagadguru' found in canonical texts, in the sense used for ācāryas, or is it even recognized by most Hinduism sects as a valid title?

Comment: hey i had asked question number 1 to swami Mukundananda ji his direct disciple! Can i post his answer here for you?

Comment: Yes you can post the answer. No need to ask for our permission :)  @Harsh

Comment: Yes, please do post it. But be careful to aptly reference it, for just saying - *I heard from someone* - won't do it on this site. @Harsh

Answer (score 3):

I am including a brief account of Shree Maharajji's life from Swamiji's book, Spiritual Dialectics.  This will help you understand him better.

===========================================

Eternally liberated Saints sometimes descend upon earth, from the divine abode of God, for the welfare of humankind. Jagadguru Shree Kripaluji Maharaj is one such divine personality.

"Shree Maharajji," as he is lovingly called by his devotees, was born on the auspicious full moon night of Śharat Pūrṇimā, in the month of October, in 1922, in the village of Mangarh, near Allahabad in India. He spent his childhood in youthful fun, playing games and frolicking with his young friends. But at the same time, he would display intense gravity and excel effortlessly in his studies. Then at the age of fourteen, he left the village and attended three universities, in Kashi, Chitrakoot, and Indore respectively. There he covered a whole series of courses in the space of just two-and-a-half years.

At the young age of sixteen, he suddenly gave up his studies and entered the dense forests of Chitrakoot. There he spent his time absorbed in intense of love for Radha Krishna. Often he would lose all external consciousness, and go without eating and drinking for many days at a stretch. For long periods, he would remain in mahābhāv, the highest stage of devotion that manifests in Radha Rani, the Divine Mother of the universe. The very same manifestation of mahābhāv love was last seen in Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, about 500 years ago. Maharajji emerged from the forest after two years to begin his mission of revealing the glories of the path of divine love to the world. He then started conducting satsaṅgs, congregational spiritual programs, that brought about a bhakti revolution in the states of Uttar Pradesh and Rajasthan in the 1940s and 50s. He would lead devotional chantings imbued with intense devotion, which would continue throughout the night. These kīrtans, which he wrote himself, have been compared by scholars with those of Meerabai, Soordas, Tulsidas, and Ras Khan. Shree Maharajji's divine kīrtans have secured a place for themselves in the hearts of devotees across the globe.

After accepting the title of Jagadguru, Kripaluji Maharaj travelled throughout India for fourteen years. He would deliver month-long discourses in each city, unravelling the mysteries of the scriptures before tens of thousands of people who would throng his lectures. Shree Maharajji's lectures enchanted the masses with humour, worldly examples, practical instructions and playful chastisement, much to the delight of the crowd. It was a unique experience as he made the deepest scriptural truths accessible to everyone in the simplest language.

It is Shree Maharajji's vision that every soul should get a chance to practice bhakti or devotion in its simplest form, so that the soul may attain its true goal of God-realization. In order to help people around the world in their quest toward this goal, Shree Maharajji has trained devotee preachers and sent them to different parts of the globe. He has also created huge āśhrams, to provide facilities for devotees who wish to practically apply the teachings in their lives.

==============================================

Answer for que number 1) For ordinary souls under Maya, it is stated to learn and understand the scriptures from a Guru who is both well versed in the scriptures and has realized knowledge of God.

Note:-  THIS ANSWER WAS PROVIDED BY SWAMI MUKUNDANANDA'S OFFICIAL TEAM

Answer for que number 2) MAHAMAHOPADHYAY PROF.shivji upadhyay MAHAMANTRI OF KASHI VIDVAT PARISHAD HAS TALKED ABOUT THE TITLE OF JAGADGURU GIVEN TO KRIPALU MAHARAJ!
HE POSITIVELY AFFIRMED IT THAT HE HAD ALL THE QUALITIES OF VIDVAN!

Comment: So by this logic - *"For ordinary souls under Maya, it is stated to learn and understand the scriptures from a Guru"* - god Krishna (guru Sandipani), and Sri Rama (guru Vasistha)... These were ordinary souls "under maya", while Kripalu ji was born-realized? Interesting!

Comment: @ vivikta I had similar thought! That's why only i asked in advance about posting answer given by SWAMI MUKUNDANANDA'S team!

Comment: As Rick ross already mentioned, there's no requirement whatsoever, in here to ask for permission from anyone to post any question or answer, it's a site open for all. In any case, this reference is weak, IMO. But any way, thanks for the effort, it does help a bit!

Comment: @vivikta if you find your answers in future plz dont forget to answer here!

Comment: I think I know the answer, I just want more proofs to finally write it with proper citations, in case noone does.